# Deploying React project to GitHub Pages

Tags: node.js, git, github

I am a contributor on [Chingu Voyage Project](https://github.com/chingu-voyage6/Geckos-Team-20).
When I run `npm run deploy` I get error like this:

```
git-upload-pack '.': git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! budget-app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -b master -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the budget-app@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you set the repository?

Comment: Yes. Repo is correct. Maybe it's because I am a contributor (not an owner of account)?